# How to get LINQ-to-SQL-like functionality with PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql

I've only ever used MSSQL and C# with Visual studio. I am trying to get the hang of PostgreSQL. One thing I'm really struggling with is having to ditch LINQ to SQL. Closest thing I've found as a solution to this is an old, no longer supported project called DbLinq.

After finding very little documentation on DbLinq, and realizing that any mention of it I CAN find is years old, I am wondering if I am searching for something that I shouldn't be using in the modern day.

Long story short, is LINQ to SQL a thing of the past? If not, is it a future headache to attempt to use it with PostgreSQL?

I have a PostgreSQL server running on a Digital Ocean droplet. I can connect to it via DBeaver/myAdmin. I can even successfully communicate with it in a c# application like this:

```
string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
                  "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                  "123.123.123.23", "5432", "user",
                  "password", "dbname");

            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                Console.WriteLine("Success open postgreSQL connection.");
            conn.Close();
```

So far in my coding experience, every time I've had to access something from a db in some code I can do something like this:

```
Customer custQuery =
    (from custs in db.Customers
    where custs.CustomerID == "BONAP"
    select custs)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Contact = {1}", custQuery.CustomerID,
    custQuery.ContactName);
```

Being able to access the various tables, or columns inside the selected table right there in my intellisense seems impossible to live without.

As I try to advance myself, I just want to make sure I'm not leading myself down an outdated road that will cause me more and more issues as time goes on.

Comment: *"is LINQ to SQL a thing of the past"* - It was superseded by Entity Framework and LINQ to EF. Have you tried [EntityFramework6.Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql) or [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL)?

Comment: checkout this very nice link https://www.compose.com/articles/code-first-database-design-with-entity-framework-and-postgresql/